# Status Bar keeps showing up when dismissing MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm making an app where I need to play a movie from my camera roll. I'm using MPMoviePlayerViewController to do is, and displaying it with:

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
```

I want it to run in fullscreen mode:

```
[theMovie.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
```

This is where the issue comes up. I don't want the Options to be displayed upon launch, so I decided to set the control style to MPMovieControlStyleNone initially. But I still want the options to be available, so after searching around I found this option:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enterFullScreenMode)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

And in this method I change the control state to MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen. This causes the status bar to be displayed in my app AFTER I dismiss the movie and return to my parent view controller. My application doesn't use the status bar at all. I've tried this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

And it didn't work. I should point out this issue only shows up if I start with control state None and then switch to Fullscreen while the movie is playing, but I need to do this because I don't want the options to show up upon launch. I'm open to any ideas. Please help me eliminate the status bar once and for all.

Thanks guys :)